# Android in-app billing for non-digital goods?

Tags: android

I want to make a small app in which I sell some non-digital products. I was wondering if there is some sort of payment system with which the users can pay directly within the app? 
I only found the in-app billing for Android but this is only working for digital content. PayPal also has an app but this is more or less something on its own as far as I saw.

Thanks for hints.

Comment: Get a Payment gateway like Amazon Payments and integrate it yourself